# My implementation of k-means gives different results

Tags: initialization, cluster-analysis, k-means, centroid

I tried implementing Lloyd's algorithm and it seemed good until I ran it multiple times. Sometimes it gives the results I want, sometimes it gives strange centres.
I tried to change the condition so it stops when it has converged, but it doesn't help. Sorry for not translating comments to English, I hope it's clear enough.

The only randomness I have in the code is in the situation where my cluster empties so I replace it with a random point. I have no other idea what to do when this happens.

I can't see the problem. Can you give me an idea what might be the problem from the result figures?

[image: Plotting resulting centers and points]

[image: This is the other case when something goes wrong]

This is my code:
(A is a matrix whose rows are my points)

```
% initialization of centroids; further-first method
n=size(A,1);
dim=size(A,2);
centri=zeros(k,dim); %matrix of centroids
for i=1:n
    centri(1,:)=centri(1,:)+A(i,:);
end
centri(1,:)=centri(1,:)/n;
for j=2:k %u svakom koraku postavljamo za centar onu tocku koja je najdalje od centra 1,..j-1
    maks=zeros(1,n);
    %maks(i) je najveca udaljenost te tocke do centra =max d(x(i),c), c centri
    for i=1:n
        dist=zeros(1,j-1);
        for l=1:j-1
            dist(l)=norm(A(i,:)-centri(l,:));
        end
        if(size(dist,2)==1) maks(i)=dist;
        else
            maks(i)=max(dist);
        end
        %maks(i)=0;
        %for l=1:j-1
          %  if(maks(i)<dist(l)) maks(i)=dist(l);
           % end
        %end
    end
    [maksi, ind]=max(maks);
    centri(j,:)=A(ind(1),:);
end

indeksi=zeros(1,n);
for i=1:n 
    indeksi(i)=randi(k,1);
end  
% u centrima je postavljena pocetna inicijalizacija
br_iter=0;
tic

while br_iter<=1000
    br_iter=br_iter+1;

    for i=1:n
        dist=zeros(1,k); % udaljenosti od tocke x do centra j
        for j=1:k
            dist(j)=norm(A(i,:)-centri(j,:));
        end
        [mini, ind]=min(dist); % ind je vektor za koji se poprima minimalna vrijednost
        indeksi(i)=ind(1); % uzmemo prvi po redu
    end
    % sad radimo nove centroide koji su aritmetička sredina svih vektora koji mu pripadaju
    for j=1:k
        centri(j,:)=zeros(1,dim);
        brojac=0;
        for i=1:n
            if indeksi(i)==j 
                centri(j,:)=centri(j,:)+A(i,:);
                brojac=brojac+1;
            end
        end
        if brojac 
            centri(j,:)=centri(j,:)/brojac;
        else
            ind=randi(n, 1);
            centri(j,:)=A(ind,:);
        end
    end
end 
toc
for i=1:n
    plot(A(i,1), A(i,2), '.b');
   if(i==1) hold on;
   end
end

for i=1:k
    plot(centri(i,1), centri(i,2), '+r');
end
hold off
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with centers all zero is not a recommended approach.
After the first iteration, all but one of these centers will be empty. So randomness *does* have an effect on your result.

The results you show are *typical* for k-means. It does not guarantee to fond the optimum, but it can get stuck in a "local optimum".

So I don't think there is an error in your code. Just the starting condition is not chosen very wisely & you are mistaken to expect k-means to always give good results.

Comment: Setting them to zero is just the initialization of the variable. I initialize them using further-first method. I fixed the problem of empty clusters by picking the cluster centroid of that cluster to be the point whose distance from the centres is the largest and removing that point from it's assigned cluster. But in that case doing n*k iterations which is surely not optimal.